# Arduino working with strings

Tags: c++11, arduino

I am trying to get my arduino uno to receive commands via the serial monitor. The command will always be sent as #RANDOM_COMMAND%, so I need to remove the # and the % from the string. The code below works however I've been told that it's unsafe because sometimes the connection will be broken and the command won't be received entirely.

```
      // wait for a message to come in
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    message = Serial.readStringUntil('%');
    int beginMessage = message.indexOf('#') + 1;
    command = message.substring(beginMessage);
  }
  // if the message is "REMOTE_CONTROL" then switch to the program mode for message receiving
  if (command == "REMOTE_CONTROL") {
    programMode = 4;
  }

  if (programMode == 4) {
    //digitalWrite(lampRemote, HIGH);
    if (command.startsWith("SET_RED:"))
    {
      int colourIndex = command.indexOf(':') + 1;
      r = command.substring(colourIndex).toInt();
    }
    else if (command.startsWith("SET_GREEN:"))
    {
      int colourIndex = command.indexOf(':') + 1;
      g = command.substring(colourIndex).toInt();
    }
    else if (command.startsWith("SET_BLUE:"))
    {
      int colourIndex = command.indexOf(':') + 1;
      b = command.substring(colourIndex).toInt();
    }
    ShowColor(b, r, g);
  }
```

Is there another way to receive a string through the serial monitor and then remove the # and % symbols safely? I'm quite new with programming so the simpler the better!

Thank you!

Comment: If the string is always **#RANDOM_COMMAND%**, why not to use `int beginMessage = 1` ? (Firts index should be zero). In this case you don't even need this variable, just `command = message.substring(1)`

Comment: Read [this](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course any communication can be interrupted somehow.

The only thing you have to avoid is that your code stops working. As long as you keep on listening for new commands it does not matter if you receive broken commands at some point. Just process the next one.
You can simply ignore them or usually better send an error message if you receive invalid commands. So whoever talks to your device will know that something went wrong.
If you receive a valid command, send a receipt.